# Как объединить значения из разных input и textarea и добавить доп.текст?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Но если значения не введены, доп текст так же не появляется.

```html
<input type="text" name="it1" autocomplete="none">

<textarea name="tt1" autocomplete="none"></textarea>

<input type="checkbox" name="" id="ch1" autocomplete="none">
<label for="ch1"></label>

<select name="sel1">
    <option style="display: none;"></option>
    <option value="">1</option>
    <option value="">2</option>
    <option value="">3</option>
</select>


<div id="go_out">Собрать</div>


<textarea name="output" autocomplete="none">

Первый инпут: /данные из input[name="it1"]/

Просто текст: /текст из textarea[name="tt1"]/

Чекбокс: Да если галочка стоит. Нет, если галочки нет.

Выбрано: /value из выбранного option в select/

</textarea>
```

Comment: Если вы думаете, что понятно и внятно объяснили суть, то вы заблуждаетесь

Comment: Пожалуйста напишите что вам не понятно, постараюсь объяснить

Comment: что значит 'объединить'? какой текст добавлять? куда добавлять? как влияет галочка и причём тут она если вопрос не о ней? "Но если значения не введены, доп текст так же не появляется." --- в смысле ужЕ не появляется но надо или надо чтобы не появлялось? какие входные данные? какие ожидаемые выходные данные? В целом, не ясно **ни-че-го**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getOut() {
    var input = document.getElementById('input-text');
    var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea-text');
    var select = document.getElementById('select-text');
    var check = document.getElementById('checkbox');
    var output = document.getElementById('output');

    if (check.checked) {
      var result = input.value + "\n" + textarea.value + "\n" + select.value;
      output.innerHTML = result;
    } else {
      var result = input.value + "\n" + textarea.value;
      output.innerHTML = result;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: не забудб добавить ид для каждого элемента и для кнопки 'Собрать' добави 'onclick=getOut()'